# Get Windows 2012 Essentials and Windows 98 to share files

Tags: windows, nfs, windows-server-2012-r2

I need to get Win98 and Win2012 Essentials working together - share files. We can't get rid of Win98, as we have specialized equipment connected to it (through special card), and newer windows versions are not supported by equipment vendor. This puts us to problems.

What do we need: windows 98 machine just needs to write files to windows 2012 folder. 
What I've tried: 
- network files sharing: folders are accessible by win7, but not by win98 as it asks only for password, not the user. Checking the "allow anonymous access" in w2012 does not help. 
- NFS: started NFS server at w2012, and installed NFS client on W98. W98 client does not see the NFS server at all.

Please advice, I don't have deep windows knowledge, whatever I've tried failed to work. The problem appeared after migrating windows server from 2008 to 2012. The same w98 system was accessing w2008 folder without installing any additional software on w98. Thank you so much.

Comment: In Windows Server 2012, consider setting a policy (windows key+r, secpol.msc > Local Security Policy > Security Settings or something) to treat anonymous access with everyone permissions, then share the folder with  everyone full permissions. Note this is pretty cancerous in terms of security.

Comment: If this is the resolution I'll then enter it as an answer. It may just be a troubleshooting step.

Comment: you could also have a local folder on the Win98 machine and synchronize it on the windows 2012 with another protocol. For example owncloud, rsync or, in last resort, FTP.

Comment: Michael: sadly, it doesn't work.
JFL: win98 has small hard drive, while the equipment gathers a lot of data. It must be saved at win2012 to which multiple users connect to access these files (that originated from win98)

Security is not any issue, small group of coworkers are using this system.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Server 2012 and Windows 98 must be on same workgroup. 
In Windows Server 2012 local policy you must change 2 options:

1. <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> --> gpedit.msc
2. Open: "Computer Configuration" --> "Windows Settings" --> "Security
   Settings" --> "Local Policies" --> "Security Options"
3. You must Change:   `Network Access: Sharign and security model for
   local accounts`  to `Guest only - local users authenticate as Guest`
   (default is Classic - local users authenticate as themselves)
4. Restart server
5. <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> --> gpedit.msc
6. Open: "Computer Configuration" --> "Windows Settings" --> "Security
   Settings" --> "Local Policies" --> "Security Options"
7. You must enable :  `Accounts: Guest account Status` (default is
   disabled)